# Custom height and width of SVG image in angular4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, svg

I am accessing an API where in json object I am getting svg image string after sanitizing the image string

```
this.apiService.receiveImageAsNonJSON("http://localhost:8080/icreate/getViewImagesBySubCategory", subCatName).subscribe(viewImageDataSet => {
        this.masterImageList = viewImageDataSet;

        var masterImageListLength = this.masterImageList.length;          
        // Calculate number columns , number of rows is fixed at 7
        let colCount = Math.ceil(masterImageListLength / 7);

        for (var index = 0; index < masterImageListLength; index++) {
            // Sanitize image string
            this.masterImageList[index] = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.masterImageList[index] as string);            
        });
```

Now i am displaying the image in html by using **[outerHTML]** property. I am getting the actual size of the svg, But I want my custom size. How to fix it out. anyone please give light. Thank you in advance --Midde

Here I have attached the screen shot, and mark the height and width in blue circle which I want to customize.
[Output Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60Mtj.png)

Answer (score 0):

it's quit ugly but you can try the NgStyle directive (https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

Can you try the following code:

Component .ts

```
            sizeOuter():string{
            var resizeComment:number;
            resizeComment=window.innerWidth-45/10;
            return resizeComment + 'px';
        }
        heightOuter():string{
            var resizeComment:number;
             resizeComment=window.innerHeight-45/10;
            return resizeComment + 'px';
        }
html:       

<div [ngStyle]="{'width': sizeOuter(),'height':heightOuter()}" [outerHTML]="image.thumbNailImage">i j</div> </div>
```

with best regards,

Comment: `<div *ngFor="let image of imageArr; let j = index" (click)="setAsPreview( i , j)"
              [class.searched-image-thumbnail-active]="image.selectStatus">
          <div [outerHTML]="image.thumbNailImage">i   j</div>
         </div>
        </div>`

Comment: Thanks for your response actually `<div [outerHTML]="image.thumbNailImage">i   j</div>` portion is printing my output, now i want to make the output means the svg image with custom size. I have attached the screen shot as well

Comment: Can you try the following code: 

Component .ts
        sizeOuter():string{
            var resizeComment:number;
            resizeComment=window.innerWidth-45/10;
            return resizeComment + 'px';
        }
  heightOuter():string{
            var resizeComment:number;
             resizeComment=window.innerHeight-45/10;
            return resizeComment + 'px';
  }
html:  
  
<div [ngStyle]="{'width': sizeOuter(),'height':heightOuter()}" [outerHTML]="image.thumbNailImage">i j</div> </div>

Comment: I found a solution in simple way, as i am accessing outerHTML and in this content there is a tag svg, I just simply add a style in css `:host >>> svg {
 height: 70px;
 width: 70px;
}
` Now its working as per my requirement. :-)